# ¿Cómo es diferente estas 2 expresiones regulares en python?

Tags: python, regex

Utilizando Python, encontré este ejemplo para separar números del resto de caracteres

```
import re

re.split("(\d+)", "abc123def")
# ["abc", "123", "def"]
```

¿Por qué son necesarios los paréntesis en la expresión regular?

si los remuevo el resultado es el siguiente:

```
["abc", "def"]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

De la [documentación oficial](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.split) de `re.split`:

> *If capturing parentheses are used in pattern, then the text of all groups in the pattern are also returned as part of the resulting list.*

Que en español se traduce a:

> *Si se utilizan paréntesis en el patrón, el texto de todos los grupos del patrón también se devuelve como parte de la lista resultante.*

En otras palabras, si colocas los paréntesis, la parte de la  cadena que estás matcheando colocada entre paréntesis también se incluirá en el resultado del `split`. Si no lo incluyes, se omitirá. El ejemplo de tu pregunta lo ilustra perfectamente.